# How to re-create trigger on MV

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, materialized-views

We have two Oracle DB instances: ORIG and REPL with a DB link between them.

There are tables in ORIG and every table has a materialised view log (MVL). MVLs are used to refresh materialised views (MV) that are located in REPL.

Other users in REPL have priviledge to select from MVs. Some MVs in REPL contain after insert triggers.

In case we need to alter table in ORIG (e.g. add a new column), there is a procedure that does the following (to ensure the MV in REPL has the same structure as the table in ORIG):

- alter table in ORIG
- alter MVL in ORIG
- **drop and re-create MV in REPL** (so that it has the same structure as the table in ORIG)
- grants privileges on MV in REPL

The reason for the last action (grant privileges) is that since the MV is dropped and re-created, all related objects (grants, triggers, ...) are lost.

My question:
Since some MVs contain triggers, I need to modify the procedure so that it also re-creates those triggers. 
Trigger codes differ (table by table). I know I can hardcode something like

```
if table_name = 'tableA' then

create triggerA
...
```

but I believe there is a better solution.

Any tips?

Comment: one solution can be to store the definition of trigger from all_triggers dictionary table to temporary table and read that table to recreate triggers.

Comment: Bhanu Yadav: good idea, thanks. I will give it a thought tomorrow.

Comment: If the source table and MV structures have changed will the trigger code have to change too? Either way, it seems like you are starting to hand-roll a database deployment process: maybe you should consider a product such as Liquibase which works with source control and build tools (Maven, TeamCity).

Comment: APC: No, even though the source table changes, the trigger code remains the same.